# comparing two mismatched matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices that don't match in dimensions. A is a 16x2 matrix and B is a 17x2 matrix. First I want to find any numbers in the first column of A and B that is leq 90 for example. Let's say there are 8 numbers in the first column in A and 6 numbers in the first column of B that is leq 150.  Then I want to be able to compare A to B such that if any number in A is within a tolerance number of B (first columns only) then I want to keep that number in A else delete the entire row in A. For example, if the 8 numbers in the first column in A = [25, 34, 45, 55, 66, 75, 84, 110] and that of B = [10, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110]  and want to find any two numbers that are within +-5 of each other once to get the result
C= [34, 45, 66, 84, 110]. Notice that I needed either 45 or 55 but not both. C of course would be a 2x1 matrix but the values in column 2 are irrelevant for comparison. 
Thank you

Comment: following your rule, you will get 25 (+5 to 30), not 34 (-4 to 30 but 30 used), 45 (+5 to 50), not 55 (-5 to 50 but 50 used), 66, not 75 (70 used), not 84, 110 => `[25, 45, 66 110]`, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your A and B matrices after the checks look like these(as per your values)

```
A = [[25; 34; 45; 55; 66; 75; 84; 110] (1:8)']; % size 8 x 2  
B = [[10; 30; 50; 70; 90; 110] (1:6)']; % size 6 x 2
```

Define tolerance and create a 8 x 6 matrix that compares the absolute difference of every element in 1st column of A to every element in 1st column of B:

```
tol = 5;
C = abs(bsxfun(@minus, A(:,1), B(:,1)'))<=tol;

>> C

C =

     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

Each element==1 in the above defines a match inside the tolerance for some element of B. Reject multiple matches by keeping only the first match in the matrix (you can expand to keeping a random one).

This means if you find match in B for some A, ignore all other B for this specific A

```
D = C; % initialize matrix of unique elements
for i = 1:size(C,1)-1 
    D(i+1:end, C(i,:)) = 0; % if more than one match, keep only first
end

 D =

     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

Finally, use any to specify only those lines in D, i.e. elements in A that have at least one match in B and reject all else

```
A(~any(D, 2), :) = []; % reject points that don't match 

>> A

A =

    25     1
    45     3
    66     5
   110     8
```